# How to convey on-scroll loading has reached the end

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, infinite-scroll, user-experience

I have implemented an on-scroll loading which fetches some chunk of data  every time the scroll reaches the end of the viewing area. After some point of time when there would be no more new data to be shown, how should I convey to this to the end-user from a UX point of view?

I was thinking of few options such as displaying a tooltip which automatically vanishes after few seconds. Other option would be something similar to [rubber banding scrolling](https://www.cultofmac.com/489256/bas-ording-rubber-band-effect-iphone/) from Apple. Any other approach that can be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowledge of what the use-case is (i.e. has user performed a search or just scrolling a list from elsewhere), in general, two good options:

- Follow Slack's "You are upto date! + icon" little image on the last
  elastic scroll at bottom. Or, for example, "That's all we've got just
  yet! Check your email for more or Search for [term] instead".
- Use a progress-bar type of indicator like when you read an article on
  Medium --> as people scroll down, they'll have a live indicator of
  getting to the bottom of the list.

Comment: These are some really good suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like dead ends in my applications. If the user hits the bottom of your list and is still searching, he probably has the wrong search terms. I'd place a box along the line of "Haven't found what you're looking for? Try a different search term" and link that to the search box.

Even if it's not a search, once the user hits the bottom without successfully finding what they where looking for provide them with an alternative.

Hope this helps you.